# I cannot use 'action.devices.traits.Modes' in Korean

Tags: actions-on-google

It can be used by setting 'modes' in English.

But, if you set 'modes' in Korean, it is assumed that it does not work.
How can I fix it?

```
{
  "availableModes": [{
    "name": "mode",
    "name_values": [{
      "name_synonym": ["모드", "변경"],
      "lang": "ko"
    }],
    "settings": [{
      "setting_name": "1",
      "setting_values": [{
        "setting_synonym": ["일", "일번"],
        "lang": "ko"
       }]
     },
     {
       "setting_name": "2",
       "setting_values": [{
         "setting_synonym": ["이", "이번"],
         "lang": "ko"
       }]
     }],
     "ordered": true
  }]
}
```

Comment: Are you using a custom library? Where does `ActionDevicesAttributeModes` come from?

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: You should file a public bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148

Answer (score 0):

If you're having an issue getting your attributes to be properly registered for a device, you should [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) on the smart home issue tracker.